# Retrieve Taxonomy Term by Field in D7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a vocabulary with a field "legacy_id" which is a primary key another related system.  I am building a routine to update the data in the drupal system based on changes in the related system.  Other then hitting the DB directly, is there a way to retrieve the tid or the entire term from the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7),

Here is the sample code,

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->propertyCondition('vid', 1) // change 2 to any vocabulary ID
  ->fieldCondition('field_test', 'value', 'test');
$terms = $query->execute();
```

First param to [fieldCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3a%3afieldCondition/7) is the field name, second one will be the column name for example for text fields column name is **value** and for term reference field **tid**, then the final one is to specify the value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is ```->entityCondition('bundle', 'voc_name')``` works as well instead of ```->propertyCondition('vid', 1)```?